# Third (?) normal form of a relation

Tags: sql, database-design, relational-database, third-normal-form

Let's say I have a website, where any person can buy and sell items and 2 registered users can send messages to each other regarding a product. One of the relations in my database is:

```
Message
--------
idMessage (PK)
Sender
Recipient
idObject
Subject
```

Of course one of the sender or the recipient should be either the seller or the buyer of a product. My question is if this relation is in 3rd normal form. Of course it is in 2nd normal form, because every non - key column is fully functionally dependent on the primary key.

Example:
Let's say that `userB` is the seller(owner) of the product `#1234` and `userA` is the seller(owner) of the product `#1000`. We have the following table:

```
idMessage| Sender| Recipient | idObject| Subject
________________________________________________
    1    | userA |   userB   | #1234   | size  
    2    | userB |   userC   | #1234   | discount
    3    | userA |   userB   | #1000   | size
```

Apparently, `idObject` in the above table determines the seller of the product. In each case the seller must be either in the "Sender" column or in the "Recipient" column. The point is the [Sender] or/and [Recipient] cannot determine the idObject, as we can see in the example above. Thus, we have 3NF, since all the non - key columns are functionally depedent only and only on the primary key.

Comment: Beware that "since all the non-key columns are determined only by the primary key" (guessing at what you meant to write, since what you wrote doesn't make sense) is not valid justification. Correct would be that all the non-key columns are *non-transitively* determined by *every* key *and it is in 2NF*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You are misusing the term "determines".**

An attribute set determines another when a subrow value for the first only ever appears with at most one subrow value of the other. Since idObject can appear with multiple values of Sender and multiple values of Recipient, it doesn't functionally determine either of them.

Your description and common sense don't suggest any functional dependencies hold other than the ones implied by idMessage being PK. So this is in 3NF and BCNF.

In fact if I give you an idObject value you can't tell me *anything at all about what this table looks like* other than what its heading and idMessage being PK tell you. So it's in 5NF. (And DKNF.)

(I can't even figure out a definition of "determines" that makes sense of what you write. Maybe you consider the *owner* of an object to be involved in "determining". If you required that either the sender or recipient of a message its object's owner then whenever an idObject value appeared there would have to be a single value that appears in every (Sender, Recipient) subrow as either Sender or Recipient. But that constraint is not a functional dependency and it doesn't imply that there is a functional dependency. So the relation would still in 3NF.)

Comment: You are right. I misused the the term "determines". Thanks for your clarification.

Answer (score 1):

So, the question should be,  is there a transitive functional dependency? if the answer is yes, then this is not a 3NF.

Not sure if I completely understand the `idObject` attribute, but if [idMessage] determines [idObject] via [Recipient] or [Sender] then we have a transitive functional dependency hence this **would not** be a 3NF. If [idObject] is determined by the [idMessage] attribute then all non-key attributes are fully functional dependent only on the primary key [idMessage] and this **would be** a 3NF.

You may want to add some explanation on What is `idObject` ?
Hope this helps.

Comment: okay, that's more clear, then looks like  the idObject determines [Recipient], I would not keep these two in the same table if you want them to be 3NF, another way to have this messaging system functionality would be to have the Message table as follows Message(idMessage,Sender,Subject) and have another table MessageRecipient(id, MessageID, Recipient, idObject) that way you would also be able to reply to messages I found something here http://www.vertabelo.com/blog/technical-articles/database-model-for-a-messaging-system

Comment: and yes, you're in the first case I mentioned

Comment: I am terribly sorry but I altered my example a little bit, in order to be more concise. Is it quite clear now?